# How can I change Playwright inspector default window size?

Tags: playwright

I would like to increase the default size of the playwright inspector window when I use the debug mode. I'm using typescript to code.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but you can always file an issue in the Playwright repo: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright